# How to do addition in JQuery with .Val?

Tags: jquery

I was looking at jQuery tutorials on how to add, but all I get is NaN with the alert.  What else do I have to do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addsection').on("click", function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) + 1;
    alert(value);
    $(".addsection").val(value);
    $(".adddesc").append("<input type='text' name='addsection[]' id='addsection" + value + "' class='form-control' value='" + value + "'/>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action "test4.php">
    <button type="button" class="addsection" name="addsection[]" id="addsection" val="1">Add Section</button>
  </form>
  <div class="adddesc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and if it could, the name of the attribute would be `value` not `val`.

Comment: should I use type="number" then?  I was using it as a place holder.

Comment: depends on what you want it to be...

Comment: @empiric Yes, buttons can have a value attribute

Comment: @j08691 welp, yes I was wrong. Don't comment premature.

Comment: I don't get the negative vote when this is a legitimate question.

Comment: Here is your [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERoHj.png).

Comment: @DDJ probably because your Question can be closed as off-topic: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change val to value on your button.

```
<button type="button" class="addsection" name="addsection[]" id="addsection" val="1">Add Section</button>
```

Should be

```
<button type="button" class="addsection" name="addsection[]" id="addsection" value="1">Add Section</button>
```

Comment: This was it... looking at too much JQuery code gets your mind stuck on it :)